# Is it possible to subscribe to a WebSocket in a serverless fashion using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

A website offers a websocket to get real-time data from. I'm trying to record data received from the websocket in a DynamoDB table for a data source for a serverless application. Their example of how to use the websocket is some Node.JS code using socket.io-client. Being JavaScript I thought to use an AWS Lambda function but they are not purposed to run constantly. Is there an AWS service to handle this sort of subscription? I don't want to make a small EC2 instance to run a tiny application just for this purpose.

Things I've looked at:

- Lambda functions - Only for short executions not long running tasks.
- SNS subscriptions - From what I understand this needs to subscribe to an SNS publisher.
- Kinesis Stream - Requires producer to use Streams PUT API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems like the whole concept of serverless is contrary to a long running, stateful server process that maintains webSocket connections to clients.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm looking for a service that is the client that receives the new data pushed out from the websocket.  That seems like a reasonable thing to wish to implement in a serverless framework.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: I am also looking form something like this, did you find anything useful ?

Comment: We also need this.  I wish someone had built a service that converted websocket messages into webhooks that would be easy to consume via Serverless.

Comment: This would be awesome. Running an EC2 instance to listen to websockets seems overkill, AWS could provide a service that allows you to listen to websockets and run something (e.g add a message to SQS, make an HTTP call, etc) such that you'd pay for usage (e.g for every time your trigger got activated). It makes sense because AWS can use a single server for multiple customers, pretty much how it works with Lambda and other serverless services.

Answer (score 27):

If we are talking about to be the client, there's no solution/service, until now, on Amazon AWS that is serverless and stays alive just for the socket's living time (from connect to disconnect).

Unfortunately, I think we are left to work with instances for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent quite some time finding a solution for the same problem but there  doesn't seem to be a way to keep a websocket client running except for using an ec2 server.

The maximum running time of a Lambda function did increase to 15 minutes which could make it worth invoking a function that keeps connecting a client for up to 15 minutes.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/

using the pricing calculator it looks like it would be $5 at minumum to always keep a client running

Unit conversions Number of requests: 4 per hour * (730 hours in a month) = 2920 per month Amount of memory allocated: 128 MB x
0.0009765625 GB in a MB = 0.125 GB Amount of ephemeral storage allocated: 512 MB x 0.0009765625 GB in a MB = 0.5 GB Pricing calculations 2,920 requests x 900,000 ms x 0.001 ms to sec conversion factor = 2,628,000.00 total compute (seconds)
0.125 GB x 2,628,000.00 seconds = 328,500.00 total compute (GB-s) 328,500.00 GB-s x 0.0000166667 USD = 5.48 USD (monthly compute charges) 2,920 requests x 0.0000002 USD = 0.00 USD (monthly request charges)
0.50 GB - 0.5 GB (no additional charge) = 0.00 GB billable ephemeral storage per function Lambda costs - Without Free Tier (monthly): 5.48 USD

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway now supports WebSockets where you can handle the events in Lambda and also respond in a simplified way. For more information refer [Announcing WebSocket APIs in Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/)

[image]

Also there are two other services in AWS you can use to achieve this,

- [AWS IOT Websockets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html):- The idea is clients will subscribe to IOT Topics and from Lambda it will push messages to client.

[image]

- [AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) (Newly Introduced):- Having a layer in between Lambda and DynamoDB which will provide WebSocket support.

Note: You might need to request for the preview of AppSync at the moment.

Comment: The question is about consuming Websocket service *as a client*. The information you listed is about how to create a Websocket service - the server-side of it.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score -5):

[API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/) directly supports websockets. So you can connect you connect APIGW websocket api to a lambda function and connect this to DynamoDB.

Detailed step by step guide for [setting up websockets in APIGW](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-requests.html) is available.

An example setup might be:

```sh
# 1. Create API Gateway Websocket
# 2. Create integration
aws apigatewayv2 create-integration 
  --api-id APIGW_ID --integration-type AWS_PROXY 
  --integration-method POST
  --integration-uri arn:aws:apigateway:REGION:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/LAMBDA_ARN/invocations
```